# Using django-celery,how do I get the worker to process tasks defined outside of tasks.py?

Tags: celery, django-celery, worker

Is it even possible to define tasks outside tasks.py?

Comment: @csm_mgr :  I have some 'def's that will be written by someone else and,and I am just supposed to run these from different modules using celery.There can be just one tasks.py,and the people writing these 'def's cannot access it.

Comment: Can you access tasks.py and import their functions there?

Comment: @cms_mgr : Yes..that is one possible solution,but I wanted the process to be as automated as possible,such that if the people writing the def's used a task decorator,it would automatically be given to the worker when used with .delay(),and I do not have to take care of each task individually by wrapping it in the tasks.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define tasks outside of `tasks.py`, you just need to tell the workers where the tasks are.  You can do that using the `CELERY_INCLUDE` setting (or the `-I` argument to `celery worker`)

If you mean sending task source code to the workers then that is a more complex problem.  It can be solved but it will be very limited.